# Python character generation

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, char

Is there an equivalent Python function to JavaScript's `String.fromCharCode`?

The use case is a string generator and I'd like to use the ASCII decimal or hex values to generate the characters (numbers, symbols, upper/lower letters).

JS example:

```
String.fromCharCode(97) // Gives 'a'
```

Comment: `chr(97)` should do what you want.

Comment: @B.M. there's the answer in there, but just incidentally

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The built-in `chr` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) handles this (`ord` performs the inverse transformation)